# convert seconds to DD:HH:MM in C language

Tags: c

how should i convert the seconds to DD:HH:MM format in C language?

Seconds in decimal value = 1397071 
converted Result using converter tool is : 16 days 04:04:31.

how should i do the conversion to  DD:HH:MM format in C?

Comment: Are you able to do it on paper? If yes, what's the issue you are having converting that to `c`?

Comment: Start with the days. How many seconds are there in a day? So how many days are there? And how many seconds remainder are there?

Comment: If `s` is total seconds, then `s / 60` is minutes, and `s % 60` is the remaining seconds.  Similarly, if `m = s / 60`, then `m / 60` is hours, and `m % 60` is the remaining minutes.  Just keep going.

Answer (score 1):

Read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html) (also [here](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) in PDF). Use functions from `<time.h>` documented in its §7.27

On Linux, the [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) page is very informative too.

You might want to use `time`,  `localtime`, `strptime`

And details are much more complex than what you believe. What about [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), for example! Or [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)!

Better use timing facilities provided by your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).